# Does Google Drive's 'per file' scope cascade into child folders/files?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm about to start building a small app on top of the Google Drive API.

I'm a little bit nervous about giving the app full permissive scope to access a user's Drive and would prefer to give it a 'per file' access scope.

The basic idea is that the app would initially create a folder (let's call it the App Folder) in a user's Drive. I then want my app to also have access to the files and subfolders inside that particular App Folder, regardless of how they were created/uploaded to Drive (but without having access to the rest of the user's Drive).

So, my question (before I build this thing out) is this: does the 'per file' scope also allow the app to access (read/manage/move) any child files/subfolders inside the App Folder that were not created by the app.

In other words, does the 'per file' scope cascade down from the App Folder into child folders and files?

Or, is the 'per file' scope ***solely*** for files that were *created* by the app itself?

Basically, what I'm after is a Google Drive equivalent of Dropbox's 'App folder' as described here --> https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/gs

Anyone know - I've struggled to find an answer to this so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Per-file scope is for files that were created or explicitly opened by the user with that application. This permission does **not** cascade, but of course if your application creates the folder, it can create files within there, and will not have access to read other files.

This is not the same as the Dropbox application folder, it is a tighter permission. Google are working on other features in this vein, so please stay tuned

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :o)

Sounds like full permissive scope is the only option for now. 

Do you know if there's a rough ETA/roadmap for additional scopes (particularly one that might match the access levels of Dropbox's App Folder)?

Comment: This makes google drive pretty useless for a lot of purposes. Dropbox application folders are a lot more practical. A folder per app, pretty simple. Why should any app need access to my entire drive? Bad design from Google. I have an app that I need to create and I will have to use Dropbox.

Comment: @AliAfshar This answer is over five years old - have there been any update to this? I'm working on an app that opens Google Drive folders and appear to be running into this same limitation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51274573/1917313

Comment: I assume selecting the parent folder does till not cascade to its children?

Answer (score 1):

There is app folders in Google drive. However, the data here will be accessible only by the application(not by the user). And the data will be deleted as soon as application's access is revoked/ uninstalled. See

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata