# How can I use the drive.file oauth2 scope with a folder in Google Drive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-picker

I'm working on a web app that will work with users' folders in Google Drive rather than individual files. I'd like to request the minimum permissions needed by using the [`drive.file` scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3). I'm using the [Drive picker UI](https://developers.google.com/picker/) to allow the user to select a folder, which works nicely with the `drive.file` and adds the folder to the list of folders my app can access.

However, the problem is that it only grants access to the folder as if it were a single file, without also recursively granting access to all the files and subfolders inside the folder the user selected. My app currently doesn't with the Drive UI to provide an Open with... option for folders, so I don't know if that would grant the correct access permissions or not.

**How can I use the Google Drive picker UI to select a folder while using the `drive.file` scope?**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14948930/9337071 In other words, the functionality you want doesn't exist - either use `drive` and pick the folder, or `drive.file` and have the user pick everything explicitly.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the link, I hadn't seen that when I searched for existing answers. However, that answer is over 5 years old - I wonder if there's an update on that or any workarounds? My experience would seem to indicate not...

Comment: So you want your app to have access to existing files by opening their parent folder? No can do. You could look at metadata.readonly which will give you access to the files, but not their contents. Alternatively, you could create an "import" app which runs one and, importantly, does not request offline access.

Comment: So you want your app to have access to existing files by opening their parent folder? No can do. You could look at metadata.readonly which will give you access to the files, but not their contents. Alternatively, you could create an "import" app which runs one and, importantly, does not request offline access.

Comment: I assume this is still not possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for folders using Drive Picker, can you try using the [google.picker.​ViewId.FOLDERS](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) view? I've used the Drive Picker in my web app as well and I use `google.picker.​ViewId.DOCS_IMAGES` view because I'm working on image files. If this does not address your issue, it may not be supported yet.