# Accessing Contents of a Folder With drive.file Scope - Google Drive API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

I'm creating a web-app on top of Google Drive. Althoguh I want to use the most restricting scope (drive.file) I stumbled accros a problem when trying to pick a folder instead of single file.
When user picks folder with Google File Picker, my app doesn't get permission to access or even see metadata of files and folders inside that particular folder, which seems counter intuitive.

Everything works well when using non-restrictive .drive scope, but that's not an option since Google asks for verification which seems quite complicated in case of 'restricted' API scopes.
I'm currently looking into Google Drive UI integration, but I'm not sure if selecting and opening folder from Google Drive itself makes any difference when it comes to my app seeing file structure inside of that folder.
Other option I tried is to use multiple other 'sensitive' API scopes (such as drive.photos.readonly, docs, etc.) but there is a verification process for these scopes as well. I'm not sure whether verification processes differ for sensitive and restricted scopes, but I would surely prefer no verification at all.
I know there is an option to select multiple files at once, and to flatten the folder structure in Google File Picker, but I'm not looking for that kind of 'hacky' solution that is degrading to the UX of my app's users.

There have been similar questions asked
[How can I use the drive.file oauth2 scope with a folder in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274573/how-can-i-use-the-drive-file-oauth2-scope-with-a-folder-in-google-drive)
[Does Google Drive's 'per file' scope cascade into child folders/files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935308/does-google-drives-per-file-scope-cascade-into-child-folders-files?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but these are from 5/10 years ago, and hopefully something changed in the meanwhile, since this looks like a big flaw in API design by Google.

Did anyone encounter issue(s) similar to this? Or do you have any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Drive.file will only give you access to files your application has created.   If you want access to other files then you can't use that scope

Comment: That's not correct. The scope drive.files gives you access to all files your app has created AND files that the user explicitly shared with your app, via Google File Picker for example. It works well for files atm, it's kind of a bummer that it doesn't work for folders as well.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this in the meantime?

Comment: I did go through verification process for sensitive /docs scope. It went back and forth with google for 7-10 days.

Comment: Hi @MikeCarter how was the verification process? Did you have to do a CASA assessment? They are asking us to do a CASA assestment level 3 and from what I'm reading it can get very expensive. If you could share your experience we would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: @Enrique R. No CASA assesment is required for sensitive scopes, only for *restricted* scopes. I just had to comply with regular requirements (video demo, privacy policy etc.) and the email thread with them was open for about 7 days.